# Using nohup when trying to run a Python35 script?

Tags: python, linux, bash, putty

I'm trying to run a python program on a linux server using a putty console pulling the program and packages from a folder uploaded to the server through WinSCP. When I run the program normally using command:

```
python35 program.py
```

It works perfectly and begins to run. The issue is that I need to run the program on the server when my computer is turned off and the putty window is gone.

I read that you can use nohup command to do this however whenever I run:

```
nohup python35 program.py &
```

It returns:

```
ignoring input and appending output to `nohup.out'
nohup: failed to run command `python35': No such file or directory
```

At this point the program doesn't run and an empty nohup.out file is created on the WinSCP.

Why does this happen? How can I fix it? I haven't been able to find any equivalent errors on SO so far.

Comment: In most cases the command would be `python3.5`. So what is `python35` actually? A script, a link, a binary, an alias?

Comment: Not sure. What command can i use to check?

Comment: Python35 was told to me by my supervisor as the command to run python3.5. When I try to run command python3.5 it returns command not found.

Comment: then it's not installed. talk to your supervisor.

Comment: What is the output of `type python35` ?

Comment: "python35 is aliased to `/opt/rh/rh-python35/root/usr/bin/python'"

Comment: That's your problem. Use the full path to call the Python 3.5 executable, and your command should work.

Comment: A workaround is to run `alias nohup='nohup '`, since the trailing blank will allow the shell to treat anything following nohup as a potential alias. But you're better off adding a `python35` symlink in a directory that's in your $PATH, so that any program that calls it gets the right thing.

Answer (score 2):

As established above in the comments, `python35` is a shell alias. Since the `nohup` runs the given command within a subshell, aliases defined in the parent shell process will not be available.

Use the following command:

```
nohup /opt/rh/rh-python35/root/usr/bin/python program.py &
```